# Retrieve custom setting value - apex

Tags: customsetting

I created a custom setting with two fields Active__c and Age__c. In my apex code, I want to retrieve one record from this custom setting where Name='Days'. This will return only one record. Would I need to use List to get this result or can I simply get this into a variable?

Comment: How many rows are there in your settings table? Are you interested in having many Age__c and Active__c rows for different "scenarios"?

Comment: only one row. I'm not planning on having many rows.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

here you go :

```
MyCustomSetting__c cs = MyCustomSetting__c.getInstance('Days');
// you then have access to cs.active__c and cs.age__c
```